# MahApps manually invoke main window blurring

Tags: wpf, dialog, mahapps.metro

I'm calling another MahApps window from the main MahApps window using ShowModal. I'd like to simulate the blurringqfading the calling window gets when one uses the built-in dialogs, like in [here](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The maker of MahApps answered this [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2153):

> you can call the overlay methods by yourself
>
> `public System.Threading.Tasks.Task ShowOverlayAsync()`
>
> `public System.Threading.Tasks.Task HideOverlayAsync()`